# System.DivideByZeroException occurred , asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a method, like this:

```
public decimal VerschilPercentage
{
    get
    {               
        {
            return ((Run1.Netto - Run2.Netto)/Run2.Netto)*100;
        }            
    }
}
```

and this is the class:

```
public class RunGegevens
{
    public decimal Netto { get; set; }
    public decimal Herr { get; set; }
}
```

But I get every time this message:

> An exception of type 'System.DivideByZeroException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code.

So my question is:

How to skip the zero's?

Thank you

Comment: Well, have you tried anything? What do you *want* to return if `Run2.Netto` is zero? Surely this is just a matter of using an `if` statement or a conditional operator, isn't it?

Comment: Test if `Run2.Netto` is zero (but what do you want to do if it is?)

Comment: Of course I tried a lot, like try catch, I want to see the results, but skip the zero's

Comment: "Of course I tried a lot" - so why didn't you show any of that, or say what happened when you tried? (You shouldn't catch the exception - you should avoid it happening by testing whether the value you're going to divide by is zero.)

Comment: What do you mean by "skip the zero"? You *have* to return anything, as `decimal` is not nullable (even then you ´d have to return `null`). So what *do* you want to return if `Run2.Netto` is zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, you can use a short if :

```
public decimal VerschilPercentage
{
    get
    {               
        {
            return Run2.Netto == 0 ? 0 : ((Run1.Netto - Run2.Netto)/Run2.Netto)*100;
        }            
    }
}
```